# Adding chartset:utf-8 to @font-face class doesn't work

Tags: css, utf-8, metadata, meta

I have set the `charset:utf-8` property in @font-face class. But it does not  work.

When I set the metadata tag, it's working correctly.

How do I get this way to work as well?

My CSS Section:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'font-icon';
  src:url('fonts/iconfont.eot');
  src:url('fonts/iconfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/iconfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/iconfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/iconfont.svg#font-icon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  charset:utf-8;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the CSS you just put the line `@charset "utf-8";` at the top of the sheet to tell the browser the contents of the file is in UTF-8. You do the same in the HTML with setting the meta charset tag `<meta charset="utf-8">` at the `<head>` of your document. Now, if the font you are loading supports UTF-8 characters, you don't need to do anything.You can completely omit this property from your node.

Comment: @charset "utf-8"; working fine. But i need to set font-face class

Comment: You can set the `@font-face` class without setting the `charset` property. Why would you need it there? I have never seen it declared there.